# Creating grails binary plugin results in jar file which contains all groovy files with comments

Tags: java, maven, grails, grails-plugin

I'm using the grails release plugin (3.0.1) in my grails 2.3.0 plugin to build a binary plugin with

```
maven-deploy --binary
```

I also set `def packaging = "binary"` in my Plugins Descriptor Groovy script.

When I inspect the created jar file with jd-gui I can see that it contains my `*.groovy` sources with comments between the `*.class` files. I think this shouldn't be, or am I false?

Why does the binary plugin jar contain my `*.groovy` sources? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This new in 2.3 - source is now included in binary plugins by default. To disable this, add

```
grails.project.plugin.includeSource = false
```

to `BuildConfig.groovy`

Comment: Burt, does this apply to `grails package-plugin` for stand-alone plugins? I just tried, but the resulting zip still contains groovy source, no class files.